# how to order the X-axis in a box plot or QQ plot in R?

Tags: r, plot, boxplot, anova

here is a reproducible sample:

```r
library(ggpubr)
library(rstatix)
library(tibble)

da.ma <-matrix(1:22000, 10, 22) ## a sample matrix

n <-seq(max(length(da.ma[1,]))) ## naming cols and rows
for (i in n) {
    c.names <- paste("k", n, sep = "")
}
colnames(da.ma) <- c.names 

n.pdf <-seq(length(da.ma[,1]))
for (i in n.pdf) {
    r.names <- paste("text",n.pdf, sep ="")
}
rownames(da.ma) <- r.names
col.names <-names(da.ma[1, ])

da.ma <-cbind(id = seq(length(da.ma[, 1])), da.ma) ##adding the id col
data <- as_tibble(da.ma)

in.anova <- data %>%
  gather(key = "Length", value = "TTR", colnames(data[, 2:23])) %>%
  convert_as_factor(id, Length)
```

Up to here, you create the data, but when you draw the plot, the X-axis is not in the right order:

```r
ggboxplot(in.anova, x = "Length", y = "TTR", add = "point")
```

I need it to start from `k1` and go up to `k24`. However, it starts from `k1` and continues with `k10`, `k11`, `k12`, etc. The right order on the X-axis would be: `k1`, `k2`, `k3`, `k4`, ..., `k23`, and `k24`.

[image]

Comment: If you convert "Lenght" to an ordered factor it works:

Answer (score 2):

```
in.anova$Length <- factor(in.anova$Length, levels = paste0("k", 1:22))  
ggboxplot(in.anova, x = "Length", y = "TTR", add = "point")
```

Returns:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `factor()` function with predefined order as levels for Length column.

```
library(rstatix)
library(ggpubr)
da.ma <-matrix(1:22000, 10, 22) ## a sample matrix

n <-seq(max(length(da.ma[1,]))) ## naming cols and rows
for (i in n) {
    c.names <- paste("k", n, sep = "")
}
colnames(da.ma) <- c.names 

n.pdf <-seq(length(da.ma[,1]))
for (i in n.pdf) {
    r.names <- paste("text",n.pdf, sep ="")
}
rownames(da.ma) <- r.names
col.names <-names(da.ma[1,])

da.ma <-cbind(id =seq(length(da.ma[,1])), da.ma) ##adding the id col
library(tibble)
data <- as_tibble(da.ma)

in.anova <- data %>%
  gather(key = "Length", value = "TTR", colnames(data[,2:23])) %>%
  convert_as_factor(id, Length)
 

#get unique length values             
levels = unique(in.anova$Length)

#order last two digits
levels = levels[order(as.numeric(substr(levels,2,4)))]

#change length column type as factor with predefined order previously
in.anova$Length = factor(in.anova$Length,levels=levels )

ggboxplot(in.anova, x = "Length", y = "TTR", add = "point")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your X-axis **is in order**, however it is in *alphabethical order*. If you run in your console `'k2' > 'k11'` you will see what I mean.

Next, to your reproducible example.

#### Sample matrix

- I would avoid dot notation because such names looks like a base functions, and it is confusing;
- I would advise to use *space* between variable name and assignment operator - it is more readable;
- As your `data` argument you provide a vector of length 22000 (`1:22000`). At the same time you tell to the `matrix()` that you want a matrix with 10 rows and 22 columns. Since *10 x 22 = 220* only first 220 of 22000 values will be used, the rest will be ignored;
- You can use `set.seed()` and e.g. `sample()` functions to generate random data;

Finally your sample matrix generation would look like this:

```r
set.seed(67600941)

mtrx <- matrix(sample(220), 10)
```

#### Rownames, colnames

- In most of the cases, you don't need to loop in R. Most of the functions in R are vectorized;
- You don't need to save the names into separate variable, you can assign them directly;
- For columns being in order, I would use a leading zeros, which is easy to achieve with `sprintf()` function;
- You do not use row names further, but I'll leave it as it is;

Final code:

```r
rownames(mtrx) <- sprintf('text%02d', seq(nrow(mtrx)))
colnames(mtrx) <- sprintf('k%02d',    seq(ncol(mtrx)))

mtrx[1:5, 1:5]

#        k01 k02 k03 k04 k05
# text01 206 127   9   1 138
# text02 191  46 220  59  73
# text03 145  15 148 213 103
# text04  80 115 211  62  79
# text05  28  11 195 136  84
```

#### Data preprocessing and plotting

- You can use `rowid_to_column()` from `tibble` to create your `id` column during preprocessing;
- I would use `pivot_longer()` intead of `gather()` since the `gather()` is depricated;
- You don't need to care about the levels, since leading zeros put your `Length` in right alphabetical order;
- I didn't save the transformed data into intermediate variable, just to save the space.

```r
library(tidyverse)

mtrx %>%
    as_tibble() %>%
    rowid_to_column('id') %>%
    pivot_longer(-id, names_to = 'Length', values_to = 'TTR') %>%
    mutate(Length = factor(Length)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = Length, y = TTR)) +
      geom_jitter() +
      geom_boxplot(fill = NA) +
      ggthemes::theme_few()
```

[image]